# Get list of my Ethernet devices ip address in my PC with boost library

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have a PC that have many Ethernet cards.
Each of them have an IP address.
For example:

```
eth0 "192.168.1.2"    
eth1 "192.168.1.100"   
eth2 "192.168.2.1"
```

How can i get these list with boost library?

I used this code, but just return: "127.0.0.1"

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost","");
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;

while(iter != end) {
    std::cout << iter->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
    ++iter;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"localhost" specifically refers to the loopback interface, as you have found.

To see all the interfaces, query by the actual hostname; something like:

```
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(),"");
tcp::resolver::iterator it=resolver.resolve(query);

while(it!=tcp::resolver::iterator())
{
    boost::asio::ip::address addr=(it++)->endpoint().address();

    std::cout<<addr.to_string()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tested this solution but it didn't worked. and return this exception:           resolve: Host not found (authoritative)

Comment: If you add the suffix ".local" to the hostname for the query, it may get past the exception and return something useful. For me, on Mac, it lists multiple ipv4 and ipv6 addresses with .local but throws the exception without it. On Linux, one of the multiple adapter's numerical IP address shows up with .local, and one of the multiple localhost numerical IP addresses shows up without it. And on Windows, I only have one, and it shows the numerical IP address with and without .local. YMMV.